# Passing enum into wrapper function in Cython

Tags: c++, enums, cython

I have been trying to wrap a c++ class which takes in an enum variable as an argument during initialization but it seems to be encountering segmentation fault so I was wondering if what I was doing had caused this error

Foo.h

```
class Foo {
 public:
  enum AType {ABC, DEF};
  Foo(int c, enum AType a_type=ABC);
}
```

A.pyx

```
cdef extern from "Foo.h"
   cdef enum AType "Foo::AType":
      ABC"Foo::ABC"
      DEF"Foo::DEF"
   cdef cppclass Foo:
      Foo(int c, enum AType a_type);

cdef class pyFoo:
   cdef Foo *thisptr
   cdef __cinit__(self, int c, AType a_type):
      self.thisptr = new Foo(c, a_type)
```